# Method post: accents on my app's description, posting on user's wall, result in diamonds and interrogation signs

Tags: facebook, post, feed, diacritics

I'm using a http call to post information about my app in any user's wall. I do it in this way:

```
_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + user_id + "/feed?message=MSG";

_url += "&access_token=" + access_token;

_url += "&picture=" + fb_app_url + "fb_icon.png";

_url += "&name=" + String_ToUrl("MY GAMES");

_url += "&link=" + "http://www.nlkgames.com";

_url += "&description=String_ToUrl("descripción with accent")"

_url += "&method=post";

http.URL_CALL(_url);
```

This method post right the information in the user's wall, but the accents are shown by a diamond with a question sign inside it. I don't know how to make it works with accents.

String_ToUrl will encode string in this way:
"descripción with accent" = "descripci%E9n+with+accent"

What's my fail? Why the user's facebook's wall doesn't recognize the urlencoded?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of encoding it for URL, what happens if you just post the description as is?

If that doesn't work, try converting the string using HTML entities and then URL Encoding the description.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked encoding to HTML entities! I have my accents jejejeje Here a webpage with he character encoding: http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/web/codehtml.html#accent

Answer (score 0):

you could also try to replace those letters with the ASCII representation (somewhat like \u123) - that would be what the Graph API gives you when there is such a Special character (in my case it would be äöü from the german alphabet)

Answer (score 0):

Your `String_ToUrl` function doesn't encode URL in unicode aware way.

`ó` (aka ['LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH ACUTE' (U+00F3)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f3/index.htm)) should became `%C3%B3` in URL encoded form, and not `%F3` (in your case you indicated that it became `%E9` which in fact `é` character).

```
descripción -> descripci%C3%B3n
```

Be sure to use proper (and unicode aware) way to encode your parameters, in JavaScript for example [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) should be used...